# Writing solutions of second order differential equations with complex roots.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I get how to find the general solution, it’s just I don’t get how to write it in the form at the bottom please-

$$\dfrac {d^2f}{dx^2} + \dfrac {df}{dx} + f(x)=0$$

I was able to get the solutions from solving as $-1/2+i\sqrt 3/2$ and $-1/2-i\sqrt 3/2$

How do I write it like this please, I tried Euler but then ‘i’ was left in

$$e^{-x/2}(C_1\cos(\sqrt 3x/2)+C_2\sin(\sqrt 3x/2) 
$$

Comment: Warm welcome to mathematics stackexchange, I suggest you learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as it is how expect each other to present our questions. However, it seems a user has edited the question in latex for you already :)

Comment: Thanks for editing this!

Answer (score 2):

Write the solution in exponential form
$$f(x) = e^{- \frac{x}{2}} \cdot ( K_1 \cdot e^{  i \frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}x } + K_2 \cdot e^{   - i \frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}x })$$

Apply the identities
$$e^{i\alpha} = \cos(\alpha) + i \sin(\alpha)$$
$$\sin(- \alpha) = -\sin(\alpha)$$
$$\cos(- \alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$$

The final solution is
$$f(x) = e^{- \frac{x}{2}} \cdot( C_1 \cdot cos(\frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}x)+ C_2 \cdot sin(\frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}x)$$
where $\;$ $C_1 = K_1 + K_2$ $\;$ and $\;$ $C_2 = i \cdot(K_1 - K_2)$

Comment: Hi, thank you. That makes sense, when I used Euler I couldn’t see how they got rid of i! Thank you Martin

Answer (score 0):

By the roots you got, the solution must be:

$$ f(x) = \lambda_1 e^{ -( \frac12 + i \frac{\sqrt{3} }{2})x } + \lambda_2 e^{ - ( \frac 12 + i \frac{\sqrt{3} }{2} )x} $$

This becomes:

$$ f(x) = e^{- \frac{x}{2}} \cdot( \lambda_1 e^{ (  + i \frac{\sqrt{3} }{2})x } + \lambda_2 e^{ (  + i \frac{\sqrt{3} }{2})x })$$

To get the intended form, apply the identity $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$

Comment: Thanks Buraian too, I just couldn’t see how to get rid of the i term with the sin